# Pandas - nan's are not getting replaced by an udf

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I have nan's present in multiple columns and am putting it through a function like this,

```
def Change_Data_Type_DataFrame (AnyPandasDataFrame):      
    for i in range(0, AnyPandasDataFrame.shape[1]):
        Required_Column_Name = (AnyPandasDataFrame.columns[i])
        AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str)
        print(LookUp_df)
        AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].replace(np.nan,"FILLINGTHENAS")
        print(LookUp_df)
        AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
    return (AnyPandasDataFrame)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with my function.

1. All I am doing is converting the data type to string
2. Then replacing the np.nan's with "Some string"
3. Then replacing the ".0" with ""

Comment: You can check the `fillna` method of a DataFrame [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
Moreover, in python we do not use CamelCase but snake_case: `AnyPandasDataFrame` => `any_pandas_data_frame` (`df` is better in that case)

Comment: It seems like, it is working when I switched it to snake_case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can convert all columns of a `DataFrame` with one step:

```
 df = df.astype(str)
```

Then, you can use the `fillna` method to replace `NaN` in your `DataFrame`:

```
 df = df.fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
```

Your function will look like:

```
def change_data_type(df):
    df = df.astype(str)
    df = df.fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
    for column in df.columns:
        df[column] = df[column].replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
    return df
```

Not sure about the regex part, I don't have any data to try what you are doing.